# What data structure can I use for a table in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I need to store data that comes as a table, what can I use in Java to do it?

The keys that form the columns and rows are Object, so I need a structure that can be represented as a triplet:  `<Object Row,Object Col, Object Val>` where for each Row,Col there is only one val, and that for all Row X Col, there is a value.

Or should I use a simple bi-dimensional array and translate the indexes to their corresponding Object?

Comment: Yes you can use two dimension array or ArrayList of Object[].

Comment: https://github.com/jparams/data-store ?

Answer (score 8):

Guava provides a [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) collection which might be what you need. See the [Guava User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) for more information.

Example usage:

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Object> myTable = HashBasedTable.create();
myTable.put(1, 2, "foo"); // put an object in row 1, column 2.
```

If you don't want to use Guava, just use a two-dimensional array, as shown below:

```
Object[][] myTable2 = new Object[5][5];
myTable2[0][1] = "foo";
```

Answer (score 3):

If Guava is not an option, I would use a `Map<Coordinate, Val>`, where Coordinate is a custom object containing your row and column objects, and implementing equals and hashCode properly.

Comment: Because that's what the OP wants, if I understood correctly: to each <Row,Col> pair (Coordinate), he wants to associate a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<Object, ArrayList> myTable = new HashMap<Object, ArrayList>();
```